# Change Headers Color in angular 5 csv files

Tags: csv, angular5

I have download csv file in angular 5 using this code.It works successfully. but I need to change cell color in headers is there any way to do that?
this is my code what I tried to download csv file

```
import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv';
var data = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];
 var options = {
  fieldSeparator: ',',
  quoteStrings: '"',
  decimalseparator: '.',
  showLabels: true,
  showTitle: true,
  useBom: true,
  headers: ['Name','Age',''Average','Approved','Description']}

new Angular2Csv(data, 'My Report');
```

my output csv file is here
[current csv file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yQad.png)

Abut I need to change my csv file like this changing headers color and set more width and height in description cell
like this[expected csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA6ft.png)

> I didn't find any question like this and good reference to get any hint to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think that it is not possible when using a CSV file, this is because a CSV file is purely a file that contains text separated by commas which excel will then interpret and format into a more user-friendly format.

This means that there can be no formatting within the file.

If you view your CSV file in an application such as notepad it will look something like this:

```
Name, Age, Average, Approved, Description
"Test1", 13, 8.2, true, "using 'Content here, content here'"
"Test2", 11, 8.2, true, "using 'Content here, content here'"
...
```

Comment: is it possible with excel ?

Comment: I believe so yes. However I am not sure if you can export directly to an .xlsx file from angular 5.

Comment: @MichaelStaples It is possible to make it with angular 2 ?

Comment: @CHARAFISaad No, not with a csv file. As explained above there cannot be any formatting within the file.

Comment: Is it possible to change the sequence of columns?

Comment: @nik Yes, it is possible, but you will have to re-order every line to fit the new sequence though